# Correctness implementation perturbation theory on Mandelbrotset

Tags: fractals

I'm trying to wrap my head around the [perturbation theory paper by K.I. Martin](http://www.science.eclipse.co.uk/sft_maths.pdf). I've made a toy Python script to try it out using float64 as 'high precision' for the reference and calculating the rest of the pixels in float32. Unfortunately, the code I've written is doing what it should be. I have a few questions about the implementation.

My understanding is that the formula $X_{n+1} = X^2_n + X_0$ is to be iterated first in high precision. During iteration, I keep track of X_n over time. While doing this I also keep track of $A_{n+1}=2X_n A_n + 1$, $B_{n+1}=2X_n B_n + A^2_n$ and $C_{n+1}=2X_n C_n + 2A_n B_n$.

On this [math stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/939270/perturbation-of-mandelbrot-set-fractal) it is suggested that $A_0$, $B_0$ and $C_0$ should be initialised with 1, 0 and 0 respectively. However, these values are multiplied with $X$ which is a complex number. Should, for example, $A_0$ be initialised as 1+1i?

Then I iterate over all the pixels in low-precision. For each pixel Y, I calculate $\delta = \Delta_0$ using $\Delta_0 = Y_0 - X_0$. Then using this delta I recalculate Y, update $\Delta$ using $\Delta_n = A_n \delta + B_n \delta^2 + Cn \delta^3$ and the n calculate the new $Y_n$ using the new delta and the stored $X_n$. Then I check the new Y for escape as normal.

Here's the code I've written:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import copy

# Complex multiplication
def cMul(a, b):
    return np.array([a[0]*b[0] -  a[1]*b[1], a[0]*b[1] + a[1] * b[0]])

# Complex addition
def cAdd(a, b):
    return np.array([a[0] + b[0], a[1] + b[1]])

# Define a function to check if a point belongs to the Mandelbrot set
def mandelbrot(c, max_iter):
    Y = np.array([0.,0.])
    for n in range(max_iter):
        if np.sqrt(np.sum(np.square(Y))) > 2:
            return n
        Y = cAdd(cMul(Y,Y), c)

    return max_iter

# Define the range and resolution of the plot
x_min, x_max = -2, 2
y_min, y_max = -2, 2
resolution = 1000

# Generate the grid of complex numbers
x = np.linspace(x_min, x_max, resolution, dtype=np.float32)
y = np.linspace(y_min, y_max, resolution, dtype=np.float32)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
c = X + 1j * Y

# Set the maximum number of iterations
max_iter = 100

# Compute the Mandelbrot set
mandelbrot_set = np.zeros_like(c, dtype=np.float32)
for i in range(resolution):
    for j in range(resolution):
        x_coord = X[i,j]
        y_coord = Y[i,j]
        mandelbrot_set[i, j] = mandelbrot(np.array([x_coord,y_coord]), max_iter)

# Plot the Mandelbrot set
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 8))
plt.imshow(mandelbrot_set, extent=(x_min, x_max, y_min, y_max), cmap='hot', origin='lower')
plt.colorbar(label='Iteration count')
plt.title('Mandelbrot Set')
plt.xlabel('Real axis')
plt.ylabel('Imaginary axis')
plt.show()

# Keep track of X, A, B and C in high precision
def mandelbrot_history(max_iter, Xn, An, Bn, Cn, dtype):
    z = np.array([0.,0.], dtype=dtype)
    for n in range(max_iter):
        if np.sqrt(np.sum(np.square(z))) > 2:
            return n 
        z = cAdd(cMul(z,z), Xn[0])

        
        An1 = 2*cMul(Xn[-1],An[-1]) + 1
        Bn1 = 2*cMul(Xn[-1],Bn[-1]) + cMul(An[-1],An[-1])
        Cn1 = 2*cMul(Xn[-1],Cn[-1]) + 2*cMul(An[-1],Bn[-1])
        Xn.append(z)

        An.append(An1)
        Bn.append(Bn1)
        Cn.append(Cn1)

    return max_iter

def perturb(delta0, Xn, An, Bn, Cn, max_iter):
    delta = delta0
    for n in range(max_iter):
        # obtain Y_n by adding X_n to delta_n
        Y = Xn[n] + delta
        if np.sqrt(np.sum(np.square(Y))) > 2:
            return n
        # calculate next delta (n+1)    
        delta = cAdd(cAdd(cMul(An[n + 1], delta0), cMul(Bn[n + 1], cMul(delta0, delta0))), cMul(Cn[n + 1], cMul(delta0, cMul(delta0, delta0))))
    return n    
        
# init comes from https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/939270/perturbation-of-mandelbrot-set-fractal Neal Lawton comment        
Xn = [np.array([0.,0.], dtype=np.float64)]
An = [np.array([1.,1.], dtype=np.float64)]
Bn = [np.array([0.,0.], dtype=np.float64)]
Cn = [np.array([0.,0.], dtype=np.float64)]
# Obtain history of Xn, An, Bn, Cn in float 64/high precision
mandelbrot_history(max_iter, Xn, An, Bn, Cn, np.float64)

mandelbrot_set_orig = copy.deepcopy(mandelbrot_set)
for i in range(resolution):
    for j in range(resolution):
        x_coord = X[i,j]
        y_coord = Y[i,j]
        # calculate delta0
        delta0 = np.array([x_coord,y_coord],dtype=np.float32) - Xn[0]
        mandelbrot_set[i, j] = perturb(delta0, Xn, An, Bn, Cn, max_iter)

# Plot the Mandelbrot set
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 8))
plt.imshow(mandelbrot_set, extent=(x_min, x_max, y_min, y_max), cmap='hot', origin='lower')
plt.colorbar(label='Iteration count')
plt.title('Perturbed Mandelbrot Set')
plt.xlabel('Real axis')
plt.ylabel('Imaginary axis')
plt.show()
```